# xslt, xml and javascript in one file.

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I'm wondering if it is possible to have xml, xslt and javascript in one file and then operate on it like it was loaded by XMLHttpRequest. Currently i have 3 files -

1. html(only few lines) + javascript which loads xml and xslt
2. xml
3. xslt

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, for a transformation of XML to HTML you will need an XSLT document which is an external document.

the transformation is done using the below command in XML document.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="abcd.xsl"?>
```

and here `href` points to the XSLT document used for transformation and it is external document